# recovering PCB to get HDD data

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, find-and-replace, firmware, chipset

It's very common that, when an HDD burns, people try to find an equivalent PCB and put their original firmware chip on it to see if works.
Maybe it sounds stupid, but why they don't replace the fried chips instead, provided it's very difficult to find a similar PCB?

Answer (score 0):

> why they don't replace the toasted chips instead, provided it's very difficult to find a similar PCB?

This would require identifying the broken IC.  It would also be required to a source for the IC that will be replaced, removing the broken IC, and then installing the new IC that was purchased.

**To put it simply it is just easier to replace the entire PCB.**  The only skill required to replace the HDD's PCB is the ability to turn a screwdriver.